# Focusing custom header with ag grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

So I’m using ag-grid with react, and I created custom header component.
In the custom header components there is react-select component,
so I’m trying to make the react-select component focused automatically when the header itself focused.
It’s working good when I’m physically click the header but when I’m trying to just go to the next header via the tab key, it won’t focused and just add focused-like border to the header.
I’m breaking my mind to find a proper api for when header is focused, just like the onCellFocused callback/prop/event, for example.
Please help :)

Comment: See [ask], and especially [mcve]. The idea is you describe what you want to do, show what you tried, and tell us what results you get. Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily.